# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): parsed is undefined and in the console "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parsed is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a Netflix clone project. For the js file Rows.js, I have written the code below.

```
***import React ,{ useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
function Rows( {title, fetchUrl}) {
    const [movies, setMovies]=useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
            const request= await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            console.log(request.data.results);
            return request;
        }
        fetchData();
        }, []); 
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Rows***
```

But the app is not loading and giving me the error `"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): parsed is undefined"`.

In the page, it shows indication of the error in these two lines of code,

```
const request= await axios.get(fetchUrl);
     | ^  13 |         console.log(request.data.results)
```

Comment: Please show `fetchUrl`

Comment: The arrow function supplied as the first argument to `useEffect` returns `undefined` when called - and the return value (a promise) of `fetchData` is discarded by the `fetchData()` call. I suggest fixing this before looking further.